# Decide duplication in a set only if the first element of a tuple(element of the set) is duplicate

Tags: python

I'm creating a dictionary, where the value is a set, compose of multiple tuples.

```
k1->{('ab', 'aram'), ('ab', 'a aram')}
k2 ->{('cd', 'b cme'), ('cd', 'cme')}
```

A set create unique elements if both element of a tuple are found duplicated in another tuple.

```
d = defaultdict(set)
........
d[k].add((kg, en))
```

But, I want to be considered duplicate, if only the first element in the tuple is duplicate.

So in the case above, because the first element is duplicate, should be:

```
k1->{('ab', 'aram')}
k2 ->{('cd', 'b cme')}
```

Comment: Why choose one of the tuples rather than the other? Sets are not ordered, so what rule did you use here?

Comment: I'm adding elements to the set, so is the first one.

Comment: Then don't add it if another one with the same first item already exists. You might want to use a more adapted data structure depending on how you manipulate your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a custom class for this by defining its hash and eq method in order for it to work with a set

```
>>> class MyObject:
        def __init__(self,data):
            self.data=data
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.data[0])
        def __eq__(self,other):
            if isinstance(other,type(self)):
                return self.data[0]==other.data[0]
            return False
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"{type(self).__name__}({self.data!r})"

    
>>> t=('ab', 'aram'), ('ab', 'a aram')
>>> x=list(map(MyObject,t))
>>> x
[MyObject(('ab', 'aram')), MyObject(('ab', 'a aram'))] 
>>> set(x)
{MyObject(('ab', 'aram'))}
>>>
```